# Create read only (get) property in constructor function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a read only property on a constructor function with Javascript. I've remixed [the syntax I've found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) but this doesn't work:

```js
function Person(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = data.firstName || "John";
  self.lastName = data.lastName || "Doe";

  get fullName() { return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName; }
}

var mike = new Person({ firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Michaelson" });

document.write(mike.fullName);
```

This will throw an exception:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I've tried other options, including:

```
{ get fullName() { return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName; } }
```

And:

```
get this.fullName() { return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName; }
```

And:

```
get self.fullName() { return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName; }
```

But none of those options work.

This one *does* work:

```js
function Person(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = data.firstName || "John";
  self.lastName = data.lastName || "Doe";
  
  Object.defineProperty(self, "fullName", { get: function () { return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName; } });
}

var mike = new Person({ firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Michaelson" });

document.write(mike.fullName);
```

But obviously this way with `defineProperty` feels clunky.

What is the correct syntax for defining `get`-only properties inside constructor functions?

Comment: You can either put it in the `prototype` (`object.prototype = { get x(){ return this._x; }}` - but you can only do this once when declaring the full prototype) or use `defineProperty`. If you are making a read-only property, you should actually use `defineProperty` to make it non-writeable. These are the only valid syntactical ways to do this.

Comment: @Jeroen are you looking to have read/write access for first/last name, but read-only access to `fullName`? If so, please re-read my answer, as I've updated it to accommodate for such a case.

Comment: @Droogans Thanks for your ideas and thoughts. You've assumed correctly about read/write acces, though I was already able to extrapolate from your original answer to those cases. I've upvoted your answer, it's useful, but it's not quite *the* answer to my question as your `Person` function is / can be no longer used as a *constructor* function as it breaks inheritance. - Guess I'm just spoiled with C#'s property syntax...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making it a POJO with options passed in all the way, but you'll still have that "clunkiness" of having `Object.defineProperties`, just without the ceremony of actually calling it (I like the shorthand way better, personally).

```
var Person = function (data) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        data = {};
    }

    data = _.defaults(data, {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    });

    return {
        get firstName() { return data.firstName; },
        get lastName() { return data.lastName; },
        get fullName() { return data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Now that I've thought about it more, I think the reason you want to include the `defineProperty` syntax at all is because you want to have read/write access to the first and last name, but read-only access to the `fullName`. If this assumption is correct, this is a pattern that I'll typically use.

```
var Person = function (data) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        data = {};
    }

    data = _.defaults(data, {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    });

    return {
        get firstName() { return data.firstName; },
        set firstName(name) { data.firstName = name; },

        get lastName() { return data.lastName; },
        set lastName(name) { data.lastName = name; },

        get fullName() { return data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName; }
    }
}

p = Person();
p.fullName === 'John Doe'; // true
p.firstName = 'Jane';
p.fullName === 'Jane Doe'; // true
```

However, there are some caveats to be aware of, mainly with object references.

```
data = { firstName: 'Jane' };
p = Person(data);
p.fullName === 'Jane Doe'; // true
data.lastName = 'Goodall';
p.fullName === 'Jane Doe'; // false!
console.log(p.fullName); // 'Jane Goodall'
```

I typically prefer having arguments passed in as something immutable, or freezing those traits by copying them out of the object and into something immutable so that updates via an object reference don't cause subtle bugs in your behaviors.

Comment: So bascially "it's not possible to use the shorthand inside a constructor function itself"? On a side note, in your example, the prototype of returned POJOs would be `Object`, not `Person`, right?

Comment: If you run this, and ask `Person.prototype`, it'll say it's a `Person` object. You can also `new` it if you want. It should behave exactly as your code sample does in your question highlighted above.

Comment: `(new Person()) instanceof Person;` [is `false` in combination with the `Person` function you posted](https://jsfiddle.net/jpxa0aj4/), as opposed to [combining it with the question's version of `Person`](https://jsfiddle.net/tqy6b887/). I'm probably misunderstanding something though?

Comment: No you are not misunderstanding this, the returned object is actually just the `{}` object. The only way to allow easy definition is to use the prototype properly and add the getters and setters there or use `defineProperty`. You are looking for syntactic sugar that does not exist in Javascript.

Comment: @Jeroen you're right! I didn't realize that `instanceof` wouldn't work. That appears to be a difference between the two implementations.